# What is the pictured hedge shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

What is the following hedge shrub?

[image]

Comment: Policy is to have one question per plant you want identified. See  https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for more information

Comment: Please edit to add: where in the world (we don't need to know how to find your house, but if you can narrow it down to 100 kilometers / 50 miles or so it really helps pick plants that might actually grow there) what time of year the picture was taken, whether there are any other characteristics of the plant that might disambiguate it (flowers? ideally with pictures, at least describe when and what color, or state that it never flowers...) etc.